# Mysql - Check if row exists

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, duplicates

I want to insert a row only if it's parent exists in another table.

**thread1 table**

```
id | content      | 
1  |  Hello World |
2  |  Bye World   |
```

**thread2 table**

```
id | content     | 
1  |  Naruto     |
2  |  DragonBallz|
```

**comment table**

```
id | thread_id| thread_type | content    |
1  |    1     |     thread1 |    hellow  |
2  |    1     |     thread2 |    bye-bye |
```

Now if i do

```
INSERT INTO comment(thread_id,thread_type,content)VALUES('3','thread2','Whatever');
```

it should fail because `3` *does not* exists in `thread2` table.

This is possible by checking from thread table. But is it possible without it ? Without doing an extra query ?

**Update**

Tables above has been updated. the `thread_type` refers to the table `thread1` & `thread2`

Comment: is it possible that while inserting you would be knowing thread_type?

Comment: You should consider having one table for threads, and a field in that table for 'thread_type', instead.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a foreign key between the two tables, using thread(id) as the parent and comment(thread_id) as the child, should do the trick.

This is the command you should run -

```
ALTER TABLE comment
    ADD FOREIGN KEY
    (thread_id)
    REFERENCES thread (id)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of multiple parents? I don't quite understand the scenario.

Comment: There is no way to create one foreign key for two different tables. It also seems like bad design to use one table that references two tables. If you're going to create two tables for your threads, you should create two tables for your comments.

Comment: This is also out of the scope of your original question, and since you've received an answer for your current question - I would appreciate if you'd accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO comment ('3','thread2','Whatever')  
select t2.id,0,0
from thread2 t2
where t2.id = '3';
```

I am assuming, id in your comment table is a primary key and auto incremented.
Above query will select id from thread2 table depending on your thread type. If id is found in thread2 table, it will insert a new row else insert zero row as zero rows are selected from parent table.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This may do that:

```
INSERT INTO comment(thread_id,thread_type,content)
(select id as thread_id, thread_type, '[content]' as content
from ((select id,'thread1' as thread_type from thread1)
union 
(select id,'thread2' as thread_type from thread2 )) threads
where threads.id=[thread_id] and threads.thread_type ='[thread_type]')
```

As in your sample

```
[thread_id]=3
[thread_type]=thread2
[content]=Whatever
```

So if there is such a parent it will be insert a row, otherwise won't insert anything.